# Disable native network card when using external

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 20, Laptop and added external usb network card
I get a weak wifi signal in my native card and better signal in the external card and see both of them as connected wifi, one with weak signal and one with strong signal.

The weak wifi is not stable, and I would like it to not hurt the stable network I get from the external card

How can I either 
1.Use both and guarantee it not to hurt the network performance (mostly stability, speed is not the issue here. i get unstable network error while using Zoom) 
2.Use only the external one

Hopefully a simple GUI solution.

Thanks

Comment: when you connect with NetworkManager, maybe a dispatcher skript is working. https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

`lshw -c network`

Look for `driver=` for each NIC. If they are different you can blacklist the one you don't want (see `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`).

Otherwise you could just down the unwanted interface -- or if it is the built in one there should be an off switch on the laptop itself (one of the Fn keys?).

Comment: I don't want to blacklist, because then when I need the internal card I need to change stuff every time. I am not much of a power user these days and would like to keep it simple. 

About the Fn button, There is one for disabling wifi, but it does it for all the wifis and this does not solve the problem